# Installing packages in conda: "[WinError 5] Access is denied"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, windows-7, conda

I am trying to install packages for use in the conda base environment on Windows 7.

I am running the conda terminal as administrator.

Trying:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2
```

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge tabula-py
```

Both fail with the error: `[WinError 5] Access is denied`.

Running `echo %PATH%`
shows python in my path: (`C:\Users\[uname]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts`)

Any thoughts on what is causing the access issue?